# Excel hyperlinks take longer to load than Outlook hyperlinks

Tags: excel, hyperlink, excel-formula

**Background:**

Comparatively, when you click a link in an email from Outlook (regardless of destination) it loads immediately, though when you click a link (individual cell) in an Excel spreadsheet there is a bit of a delay before anything loads.

The links I am using are generated by adding a destination (via right click menu, add link) to a cell with entered text/description.

I have tried to use hyperlink() function; this has the same pause before anything redirects.

---

**Issue:**

This is not a code-specific issue, but I am not finding strong (if any) documentation to explain what the pause is before Excel redirects to a link.  I am hoping to find why the pause happens and, if possible, to get the links to load more quickly (similar to Outlook).

---

**Question:**

Is there any immediate change I could make to my process to get links in Excel to redirect/load more quickly?